# Obtain number of edges of G from set {$G - v| v \in V$} where G is a simple graph with at least 3 vertices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given G is a simple graph with at least 3 vertices and {$G - v| v \in V$}, how to find number of edges of G from set  {$G - v| v \in V$}?

My attempt: Since we are given set {$G - v| v \in V$}, we can count number of edges and lets call the number of edges in this set X. Notice that the maximum number of edges can be removed from original graph G is (n - 1) where n = number of vertices. Therefore, the maximum number of edges of G is X + (n -1).

I do not believe that the way I solve this question is correct. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Is $\{G-v|v\in V\}$ given as a set or a multiset? I.e., are you simply given a list of the distinct graphs obtained by deleting one vertex from $G$, or are you also given the multiplicity of each such graph?

Comment: If $V(G)=\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ and if the graph $G-v_i$ has $e_i$ edges, then $G$ has $(e_1+e_2+\cdots+e_n)/(n-2)$ edges. I don't know if this helps with your question or not because I'm not sure what the question is.